# Nginx Why does my server serve correct content on localhost but not 0.0.0.0

Tags: linux, nginx, django

I am trying to get data from my server but if I try from `0.0.0.0/my/api` it gives a 400, but if I try from `localhost/my/api` it gives the content I need. I am using nginx and here is the config file for the server

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost 54.149.242.144;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/myapp.log;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/myapp;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Also if I do a netstat I get this for the server

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8080/nginx
```

Why would it only give me the correct content from localhost, and give me 400's from the 0.0.0.0 address? Also this is making it so I can not access the api from an outside machine. Finally I am using gunicorn as a backend server and using nginx to reverse proxy gunicorn.

Comment: `server_name localhost 54.149.242.144;`  Those are the ones it'll work for.

Answer (score 3):

The address 0.0.0.0 can be used only in certain specific context on a Linux machine. Back in the days you could use 0.0.0.0 and it was interpreted as loopback address (127.0.0.1 or localhost).

The address 0.0.0.0 is now used only for listening sockets to show that the process is listening on all IPv4 interfaces. It is nice to have this configured because you can change the IP of the server without restarting the service listening on 0.0.0.0.

I recall (I could be wrong...) that if you try to start a listener an IP from a interface that have the link down it would fail.